# Calculating the volume of a region in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, geometry

I'm attempting to solve a problem and I think that the first thing I need os the area of the region $R=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:0<x^2+xy+y^2<M\}$. Any hints would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With a 45° rotation: 
$$
x'={x+y\over\sqrt2},\quad
y'={x-y\over\sqrt2},
$$
your condition becomes:
$$
0<{3\over2}x'^2+{1\over2}y'^2<M.
$$
That's the interior of an ellipse with semiaxes $\sqrt{2M/3}$ and $\sqrt{2M}$, whose area is thus $2\pi M/\sqrt3$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $x= y , x=-y $ in the the central ellipse that has its major axis inclined at $45^0$ to x-axis

$$x^2+y^2+xy= M=m^2$$

to find intersections and compute its major/minor axes as

$$ \sqrt{2/3}m, \sqrt 2 m$$

Area is $$\pi\cdot  \sqrt{2/3}m \cdot \sqrt 2 m =2 \pi/\sqrt {3} m ^2 = ( 2 \pi/\sqrt {3} ) M$$

BTW  in Mechanics of materials Von Mises 2D failure envelope is represented this way with $m$ as each axis failure stress.